# How to compile multiple java source files in command line

Tags: java, build, javac

I know running `javac file1.java` produces `file1.class` if `file1.java` is the only source file, then I can just say `java file1` to run it.

However, if I have 2 source files, `file1.java` and `file2.java`, then how  do I build the program?

Comment: Does that mean  both the files have main method or there are 2 entrypoint of an application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-all-java-files-under-a-given-directory-recursively

Answer (score 141):

Try the following:

```
javac file1.java file2.java
```

Comment: this is hardcoded, how do we use the results from `$(find .)` etc?

Answer (score 99):

or you can use the following to compile the all java source files in current directory..

```
javac *.java
```

Comment: No, it is not recursive.

Comment: * is the symbol for a wildcard. It means all things in this directory that end with ".java"

Answer (score 7):

Here is another example, for compiling a java file in a nested directory.

I was trying to build this from the command line. This is an example from 'gradle', which has dependency 'commons-collection.jar'. For more info, please see '[gradle: java quickstart](https://docs.gradle.org/1.11/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html)' example.  -- of course, you would use the 'gradle' tools to build it. But i thought to extend this example, for a nested java project, with a dependent jar.

**Note:** You need the 'gradle binary or source' distribution for this, example code is in: 'samples/java/quickstart'

```
% mkdir -p temp/classes
% curl --get \
    http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar \
        --output commons-collections-3.2.2.jar

% javac -g -classpath commons-collections-3.2.2.jar \
     -sourcepath src/main/java -d temp/classes \
      src/main/java/org/gradle/Person.java 

% jar cf my_example.jar -C temp/classes org/gradle/Person.class
% jar tvf my_example.jar
   0 Wed Jun 07 14:11:56 CEST 2017 META-INF/
  69 Wed Jun 07 14:11:56 CEST 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 519 Wed Jun 07 13:58:06 CEST 2017 org/gradle/Person.class
```

Answer (score 2):

1.[use wildcard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lln2q.png)

2.[use options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57O6G.png)

3.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: How could this work? @file expects the file provided to contain the names of the files to compile.

Comment: sorry, i forget to check my answer. now, i paste official description.

Answer (score -7):

OR you could just use `javac file1.java` and then also use `javac file2.java` afterwards.

Comment: That does not answer the question. OP was asking if there is a way to compile multiple .java files at once.