# how to create a "package" in Java?

Tags: java

I have two classes, Parent and Child. The code for the classes are like this:

**Parent.class**

```
package test;
import java.util.*;

public class Parent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child();
    }
}
```

**Child.class**

```
package test;
import java.util.*;

public class Child {
    public Child() {
        System.out.println("A Child object has been created");
    }
}
```

I put both classes in a directory named "test". I can compile Child.java without any problem but I cant Compile Parent Class. It says that it cannot find the child class. What is the problem?

Comment: Where are you compiling these _from_?  Can you provide the command line?  These look good to me as they are.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800781/how-to-compile-multiple-java-source-files-in-command-line

Comment: CLASSPATH....famous classpath...make sure that folder containing test is in classpath

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I open the command prompt and go to the directory which .java files reside, just to clarify the name of that directory is the same as the package name that I used in the .java files. when I type in "javac parent.java" I'll get the error message. I also tried to type in "javac test\parent.java" and I could compile it but I got the error message when I typed in "java Parent". Im confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you execute the command in a error place. If you put the code in d:/test/, you should 
execute your command under the directory d:/.

So, if you change your directory to d:, you can do the right things.
javac test\Child.java
javac test\Parent.java

java test.Parent

You will get what you want..

Comment: now it compiles both classes without any problem but when I try "java test\Parent" wrong name: test/Parent!!

Comment: it shoud be "java test.Parent"  . test.Parent is the name of your class Parent.

Comment: Thank you I could compile it and run it using the instruction you gave me. now the problem is how should I setup "PATH" so i wouldnt need to type in the package name everytime that i want to run the file?

Comment: I think you make a mistake. The full qualified name of a java class is "package_name.class_name" . So you can't execute "javac" cammand without specified the full name of the class.

Comment: So you can't execute "javac" cammand without specified the full name of the class. At the same time, i think your "PATH" means "CLASSPAHT". You can get more informations about it by reading books or just google it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is to include your generated child class in class path while you compile parent class.

```
SET CLASSPATH= (the path where your child.class exists);%CLASSPATH%;
```

The above needs to be done because the parent class is dependent on the child class and cannot be compiled without it

some details can be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html

Comment: could you please be more specific on how to setup PATH??

Comment: dont tamper with PATH just use CLASSPATH. `SET CLASSPATH=(the path where your child.class exists);%CLASSPATH%;`

Comment: while you try to learn these basics keep in mind that multiple classes are usually compiled using a build tool like `Ant` or `Maven`

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your java files are in D:\test. And you compile likes this

```
     D:\>javac test/Child.java
     D:\>javac test/Parent.java
```

It will be OK for you.If you use some IDEs, your classes have no problem.

Comment: I know that IDE would do it for me easily but I want to learn the fundamentals of it. thanks for you answer.