# Run java with terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

Is it possible to run in terminal java program that contains multiple files? When I'm using

```
javac main.java
```

terminal can't find any files except main.java

Comment: that is merely compiling one class, not running. it's also not looking for any class other than main, so what is the problem?

Comment: My problem is - is it possible to compile & run this program throught terminal?

Comment: of course it is, if you use the correct instructions.

Comment: Could you pass me this instruction?

Comment: You only listed one file so only one file was compiled.  Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800781/how-to-compile-multiple-java-source-files-in-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you compile your .java files

```
javac *.java
```

then you run it by typing,

```
java main
```

where main is the class with your main method, in the terminal.

Comment: But when i use 'javac main.java' I have an error "cannot find symbol" (it becouse it couldn't find class from another file).

Comment: And that is why you type `javac *.java` to get all the java files within the same directory compiled together.