# Does inheritance across packages is possible? Also, how do we compile them?

Tags: java, inheritance

Context: Two classes from different packages (Second class in second package inherits class in first package) are connected through inheritance and made a method call to subclass from parent class.

**What I did:**

Written two classes in two different notepad files and trying executing one after other but was not possible for me to execute and showing error messages and my classes are as follows:

```
package first;

import second.Sample1;

public class Sample {

public static void main(String a[])
{
    Sample1 s=new Sample1();
    s.dis(1);
}


package second;

import first.Sample;

public class Sample1 extends Sample{
public void dis(int i)
{
System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

In Eclipse, it is giving output as 1 but in what order I should execute these codes using notepads files. Observed that compiling these classes in any order giving error messages.

Thanks much. :)

Comment: Your inheritance doesn't _do_ anything. What did you expect? P.S. you need to compile them _together_ as they have a circular dependency.

Comment: In Eclipse, it is giving output as 1... Please read the whole description. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, what else would `System.out.println(1)` produce? I was more asking about what you expected the inheritance to do in this example.

Comment: How to compile them together as I have written them in different notepad files?

Comment: That would seem to be easily [searchable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4800791/2071828).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a cyclic package dependency, which is not a good idea.

Your base class `Sample` doesn't have to know anything about its sub-classes, and when it does, it is usually a sign of bad design.

Just move the `main` method to `Sample1`, and `Sample` class won't have to import `second.Sample1`.

Comment: And then delete `Sample`? The main problem here is that this isn't really an example of inheritance in any meaningful way.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree that as posted in the question, `Sample1` doesn't inherit any state or behavior from `Sample`, but I gave a general answer for cases in which the inheritance does make sense.

Comment: I can make Sample1 to inherit any state/behavior from Sample but is not my concern. Just to know, how to compile them?

Comment: @Vishwak Once you break the bad dependency, you can compile `Sample` first and then compile `Sample1`.

Comment: `C:\Users\PE>javac -d . Sample.java Sample1.java` 
`C:\Users\PE>java first.Sample`
    `1`



Got my Answer. 

I  got this problem in middle of my development and I will try avoid this dependency

Much Thanks both.