# run java program created in intellij from command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-line, compilation

I have a simple Java Maven program that I created in Intellij. It has Two classes `Main` and `Read`. I was able to build a jar and run it. However if I zip the source code into a folder , would I be able to compile it using command line? Something like `javac` ? How should I do this? Shall I run commands in `Java` folder in the project? Many thanks.

Comment: If you use Maven there is no reason to compile your program with javac. Maven does exactly that, and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the Java class loader is concerned, a .jar or .zip file is the same as a directory containing the the files, and .jar and .zip files are generally used to distribute compiled Java packages. [Here](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/tcljava98/notes/compiling.html) you can read more about it.

For compiling the zip file: use the -classpath option to javac and java. We could, for example:

```
javac -classpath .:/users/johnr/java:/opt/jdk1.1.6/lib/classes.zip Hello.java
```

Comment: Thanks. To clarify this a bit more, this command is how to run Hello.jave after all the code has been zipped to classes.zip? I'm not sure if there are two classes, how to compile them all with javac?

Comment: to run the java file inside the folder you can write: `javac *.java`
by adding this command to the beginning you can compile multiple file. easy way is writing file name like: 
`javac -classpath .:/users/johnr/java:/opt/jdk1.1.6/lib/classes.zip Hello.java GoodBye.java`

Comment: Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800781/how-to-compile-multiple-java-source-files-in-command-line), here you can find more explanation about running multiple file.