# Cannot find symbol class Java

Tags: java, class, cannot-find-symbol

```
package com.test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car();
        System.out.println("Car speed: " + car.speed);
    }
}


package com.test;

public class Car {
    public int speed = 100;
}
```

```
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Car car = new Car();
        ^
  symbol:   class Car
  location: class Main
Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Car car = new Car();
                  ^
  symbol:   class Car
  location: class Main
2 errors
```

In console i coming in folder package, there all java files `Main.java` and `Car.java` 
And do first in console `javac Car.java`
Next i do `javac Main.java`, it writes error

I`m coding in IntelliJ IDEA, everything works fine there

Comment: Use a build tool. I recommend gradle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile multiple java source files in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800781/how-to-compile-multiple-java-source-files-in-command-line)